# Remove and replace woocommerce add to cart button

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm working on a solution where I have a ACF on each WooCommerce product. When the custom field is other than `NULL` it will add a custom anchor tag below the previous Add to cart button. This works fine, but I can't get it to work so that when the above steps are completed, the add to cart button would be removed with the hook `woocommerce_is_purchasable`. This might be a bad idea overall, because I've seen that if I use the `woocommerce_is_purshable`, and set it to false outside the `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` hook it removes both the *Add to cart* button and my custom made *Order A Catalog* button.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', function () {
    $order_a_catalog_url = get_field('order_a_catalog_url', get_the_ID());
    $order_a_catalog_name = __('Order A Catalog', 'wp');

    if ($order_a_catalog_url != null) {
        echo '<a class="button" href="'.$order_a_catalog_url.'">'.$order_a_catalog_name.'</a>';

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false' );
    }
    
}, 100);
```

Comment: If the product isn't purchasable then it may remove the entire hook where your custom button loads.

Comment: The question got answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661105/remove-and-replace-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button

Comment: From your example it looks like you should just be using an External product. None of this should be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question on stackoverflow and got the answered there. But what was the issues was that I used add_filter, had the wrong priority and used the wrong hook. The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661105/remove-and-replace-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button